# I'm unable to transform my DataFrame into a Variable to store data-values/features (Linear Discriminant Analysis)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm using LDA to reduce two tables I've created, holds and latency, down from 9 and 18 features respectively (along with a target each). I planned on using LDA for this and am currently trying to parse in the features into a variable. However that doesn't seem to be working. I receive a KeyError([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZfH9.png)) whenever I do this. My data is perfectly fine and here is the code. If anyone could tell me what's wrong with it, I'd be very grateful. Here is a tail of both my DataFrames:

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA

lda = LDA(n_components=2)
X = holds[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]].values
Y = holds[9].values
X2 = latency[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]].values
Y2 = latency[9].values
```

Comment: @seralouk Hi there, thanks for the help! I wanted to ask you two things if you don't mind: 1. If I wanted to do this for only one column, how would I go about doing that and 
2. Why does this work?

Answer (score 0):

**This error has nothing to do with the LDA or scikit-learn in general.**

**The error is coming from the way you try to index the pandas dataframe that you have.**

---

Use this:

```
X = holds.iloc[: , [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]].values
Y = holds.iloc[:, 9].values
```

Similarly, for `X2` and `Y2`.

Comment: I'm so stupid at this haha. Should have realised that. Thanks so much!

Comment: This seems to raise an IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds for latency's values

Comment: you use `X2 = latency[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]].values`. Do you have 17 columns in `X2` ??? I do not think so..